# T-SQL: Eliminating null row results from field concatenation using XML PATH

Tags: xml, field, string-concatenation

I've been doing research to find a way to concatenate fields from multiple rows into a single row in the result set. My objective is to create a list of alternate sizes for a base product number, excluding each row from naming itself as an alternate size.

I've successfully done this using the XML PATH method, but I have a catch 22.

First, the query produces rows with Null values for the concatenation results when no product records containing alternates sizes are found. I have not found a way to eliminate these null result rows.

Second: No problem, thought I. I'll create a View with my query, then take another view off of it which eliminates the rows with null results. However, the SQL View rejects the XML element that works fine just as a query.

Here is my query:

```
Select Prod2.partnumber,
   SUBSTRING(
   (
   Select ','+Prod1.partnumber as [text()]
   from Items Prod1
   where left(Prod1.partnumber,8) = left(Prod2.partnumber,8)
         and Prod1.partnumber <> Prod2.partnumber
   order by prod1.partnumber
   for XML PATH ('')
   ), 2,1000) AltSizes
from Items Prod2
```

So what I'd really love is a way to eliminate null "AltSizes". But everything I've tried to WHERE AltSizes as not null, results in an error telling me that AltSizes is not a valid field.

Thanks in advance for any help getting rid of the null results!